# MySQL subquery performance and index issue on 1 row VS range

Tags: mysql, sql

I created the query below which displays price along with a kind of delta index on past prices from the same table (the real query uses multiple subqueries on different date intervals therefore I prefere to avoid using multiple JOINs) :

```
SELECT
H1.`item_id`,
H1.`date`,
H1.`price`,
(SELECT AVG(H2.price)/H1.`price`
    FROM hive_item_price H2 FORCE INDEX (date_id)
    WHERE H2.item_id = H1.item_id AND H2.bee_hive_id = H1.bee_hive_id
    AND H2.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(H1.`date`, interval +12 hour) AND H1.`date`) AS fDelta12hrs,
(SELECT AVG(H2.price)/H1.`price`
    FROM hive_item_price H2 FORCE INDEX (date_id)
    WHERE H2.item_id = H1.item_id AND H2.bee_hive_id = H1.bee_hive_id
    AND H2.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(H1.`date`, interval +48 hour) AND H1.`date`) AS fDelta48hrs
FROM hive_item_price H1
WHERE H1.id = 3915328
```

It works well but I had to force the INDEX because MySQL does not use it otherwise and it makes it very very slow. The problem starts as soon as I specify more than 1 row in the WHERE clause (ie. "WHERE H1.id IN (3915328,3915044)" VS "WHERE H1.id = 3915328").

```
...
WHERE H1.id IN (3915328,3915044)
```

It changes the query plan and becomes very very slow (it's like a ratio of 1 VS 10000!). Indexes seams to be wrongly used. My goal is to run this against a milion prices :). I used the explain function but could not figure out how to get a similar query plan or just similar performance.

Here is the plan for the query running fast (only 1 row using "WHERE H1.id = 3915328") :

```
| id | select_type          | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra
|1   | PRIMARY              | H1    | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const | 1    |
|2   | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | H2    | range | date_id       | date_id | 16      | {null}| 61   | Using where
```

Here the new plan when changing from "WHERE H1.id = 3915328" to "WHERE H1.id IN (3915328,3915044)":

```
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len  | ref                 | rows   | Extra
| 1  | PRIMARY            | H1    | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8        | {null}               | 2     | Using where
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | H2    | ref   | date_id       | date_id | 8        | tvlr_old.H1.item_id | 19578 | Using where
```

Data looks like this:

```
id      item_id price date
3915328 4       94,00 21/06/2013 10:24:03
3915044 4       93,00 21/06/2013 10:12:03
3914761 4       92,00 21/06/2013 10:00:03
3914475 4       92,00 21/06/2013 09:48:03
3914189 4       91,00 21/06/2013 09:36:03
3913905 4       91,00 21/06/2013 09:24:03
3913620 4       91,00 21/06/2013 09:12:03
3913335 4       90,00 21/06/2013 09:00:03
3913050 4       90,00 21/06/2013 08:48:03
3912764 4       90,00 21/06/2013 08:36:03
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please `SHOW INDEX FROM hive_item_price;`

Comment: I did different tests but the current state is as follows:

`PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY hive_item_price_bee_hive_id_bee_hive_id (bee_hive_id),
KEY hive_item_price_item_id_item_id (item_id),
KEY date_ind (date,item_id,bee_hive_id,id),
KEY date_id (item_id,bee_hive_id,date,id)`

Comment: are you using innodb?

Comment: I also tried to replace the "WHERE H1.id = 3915328" by a LIMIT 1 to check if it would run fast => result: I am then completely stucked (still processing...)

Comment: I'm rereading your question now and I'm doubting about something: are you have better performances with 2 ids and the `force index` hints?

Comment: @Sebas sorry it was really late yesterday (in France). If I don't use force index, I have bad performance in any case (1 row or 2+ rows). When I use force index, I have good performance only with 1 id and still bad performances for 2+ ids/rows.

Comment: maybe you're having issues with skewed datas. I would need to have a look at it deeper to give an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the version of the query targeting only 1 row/id is more than 1000 faster than the 2+ rows/ids version and that I wasn't able to avoid the bad query plan of MySQL in that case: the fastest solution I currently found for multiple ids/rows is to use a cursor which will run the 1 row query for each id.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempPrices;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempPrices
(
  iId INT unsigned NOT NULL,
  dDateCollected datetime,
  fPrice FLOAT,
  fDelta12hrs FLOAT,
  fDelta48hrs FLOAT
)ENGINE=MEMORY;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pricefcloop;

CREATE PROCEDURE pricefcloop()
BEGIN
  DECLARE curr_id INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM hive_item_price WHERE id IN (3915328, 3915044, ....);

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO curr_id;
    INSERT INTO tempPrices (iId, dDateCollected, fPrice, fDelta12hrs, fDelta48hrs)
      SELECT
      H1.`item_id`,
      H1.`date`,
      H1.`price`,
      (SELECT AVG(H2.price)/H1.`price`
          FROM hive_item_price H2 FORCE INDEX (date_id)
          WHERE H2.item_id = H1.item_id AND H2.bee_hive_id = H1.bee_hive_id
          AND H2.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(H1.`date`, interval +12 hour) AND H1.`date`) AS fDelta12hrs,
      (SELECT AVG(H2.price)/H1.`price`
          FROM hive_item_price H2 FORCE INDEX (date_id)
          WHERE H2.item_id = H1.item_id AND H2.bee_hive_id = H1.bee_hive_id
          AND H2.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(H1.`date`, interval +48 hour) AND H1.`date`) AS fDelta48hrs
      FROM hive_item_price H1
      WHERE H1.id = curr_id;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END;

CALL pricefcloop();

SELECT * FROM tempPrices;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this query please? out of curiosity:

```
SELECT 
    H1.id,
    AVG(H2.price)/H1.`price` AS fDelta48
    AVG(H3.price)/H1.`price` AS fDelta24
FROM 
    hive_item_price H1
        JOIN hive_item_price H2 ON 
                H2.item_id = H1.item_id 
            AND H2.bee_hive_id = H1.bee_hive_id
            AND H2.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(H1.`date`, INTERVAL +48 HOUR) AND H1.`date`
        JOIN hive_item_price H3 ON 
                H3.item_id = H1.item_id 
            AND H3.bee_hive_id = H1.bee_hive_id
            AND H3.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(H1.`date`, INTERVAL +24 HOUR) AND H1.`date`
WHERE 
    H1.id IN (3915328, 3915044)
GROUP BY
    H1.id;
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried your query which run well with 1 row "WHERE H1.id = 3915328" but has the same issue for more than 1 row (ie. "WHERE H1.id IN (3915328,3915044)").

Comment: I also tried a similar version which still has the same problem.

Comment: SELECT
     H1.id,
     AVG(H2.price)/H1.`price` as fDelta48hrs,
     AVG(CASE WHEN (H2.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(H1.`date`, interval +12 hour) AND H1.`date`) THEN H2.price ELSE null END)/H1.`price` as fDelta12hrs
    FROM hive_item_price H1
     JOIN hive_item_price H2
     ON H2.item_id = H1.item_id AND H2.bee_hive_id = H1.bee_hive_id
     AND H2.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(H1.`date`, interval +48 hour) AND H1.`date` AND H1.id = 3915328
    GROUP BY H1.id

Comment: MySQL can't use indexes with 'range' JOIN's.

Comment: @Vatev: and do you have an idea of workaround for this case ?

Comment: @Sebas: run fast for 1 row/id  (<0.01 sec) and will take more than 10 minutes for just 2 rows/ids.

Comment: Your 'date' field is a `datetime` or a `date`?

Comment: @Vatev it is a datetime (yes it is really confusing but I can't change it)

Comment: The only solution I know is to convert `BETWEEN` to a `=` using an additional `date` field (which would be have a value of `date(date)` set via trigger). This only works if your range is a day (00:00:00-23:59:59).

Comment: I see the point but the example I provided is just part of the query which also includes delta index based on intervals of 15mn, 1 hour, 4 hours, 12 hours.

Comment: @doxav can you give me the explain plan of my query please?

Comment: id * select_type * table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra *
1 SIMPLE H1 const PRIMARY,hive_item_price_bee_hive_id_bee_hive_id,hive_item_price_item_id_item_id,date_ind,date_id PRIMARY 8 const 1 
1 SIMPLE H3 range hive_item_price_bee_hive_id_bee_hive_id,hive_item_price_item_id_item_id,date_ind,date_id date_id 16  102 Using where
1 SIMPLE H2 range hive_item_price_bee_hive_id_bee_hive_id,hive_item_price_item_id_item_id,date_ind,date_id date_id 16  222 Using where; Using join buffer

Comment: When I change the WHERE clause by "WHERE H1.id IN (3915328,3915329)", I have the new following plan:
 `1 SIMPLE H1 range PRIMARY,hive_item_price_bee_hive_id_bee_hive_id,hive_item_price_item_id_item_id,date_ind,date_id PRIMARY 8`  `2 Using where
1 SIMPLE H2 ref hive_item_price_bee_hive_id_bee_hive_id,hive_item_price_item_id_item_id,date_ind,date_id hive_item_price_item_id_item_id 8 tvlr_old.H1.item_id 2753 Using where`
`1 SIMPLE H3 ref hive_item_price_bee_hive_id_bee_hive_id,hive_item_price_item_id_item_id,date_ind,date_id hive_item_price_item_id_item_id 8 tvlr_old.H2.item_id 2753 Using where`

Comment: Ok thanks. I added the IN(...) to my query. Could you extrain the Explain plan from that one now please? @doxav

Comment: id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra  
1 SIMPLE H1 range PRIMARY,hive_item_price_bee_hive_id_bee_hive_id,hive_item_price_item_id_item_id,date_ind,date_id PRIMARY 8  2 Using where  
1 SIMPLE H2 ref hive_item_price_bee_hive_id_bee_hive_id,hive_item_price_item_id_item_id,date_ind,date_id hive_item_price_item_id_item_id 8 tvlr_old.H1.item_id 2753 Using where  
1 SIMPLE H3 ref hive_item_price_bee_hive_id_bee_hive_id,hive_item_price_item_id_item_id,date_ind,date_id hive_item_price_item_id_item_id 8 tvlr_old.H2.item_id 2753 Using where

Comment: @doxav, ok, now, the same but with FORCE INDEX on both h2 and h3 please?

Comment: @Sebas, I just tried your query with FORCE INDEX on H2 and H3 but it didn't improve the performance. I still have a different query plan when using "WHERE H1.id = 3915328" vs "WHERE H1.id IN (3915328,3915044)". I noticed that in the first case (WHERE H1.id = 3915328) it uses a JOIN BUFFER on H3 and no mention of "Using where" in the Extra section for H1. In the second case: it doesn't use the JOIN BUFFER on H3, "Using where" is mentioned in Extra section of H1, H2 and H3 are marked with a "ref" to H1.item_id (this "ref" is NULL in the first case).

Comment: @doxav please paste me the explain plan of my query with 2 ids and the 2 force index please

Comment: `1 SIMPLE H1 range PRIMARY,hive.....e_hive_id,hive_i...tem_id,date_ind,date_id PRIMARY 8  2 100 Using where`  //  
`1 SIMPLE H2 ref date_id date_id 8 tvlr_old.H1.item_id 217543 100 Using where`  //  
`1 SIMPLE H3 ref date_id date_id 8 tvlr_old.H2.item_id 217543 100 Using where`

Comment: @doxav what's that new value `100` between `rows` and `extras`?

Comment: Please move extended discussion to [chat], thanks :)